# PRISM navigationService is null in ViewModel constructor

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism, prism-7

SITUATION: I have these objects:

```
MainMenuView
MainMenuViewModel
MainMenuPage
```

The `MainMenuPage` contains the `MainMenuView`, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxx_App.Pages"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:xxx_App.Views"
             x:Class="xxx_App.Pages.MainMenuPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>           
            <views:MainMenuView />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The MainMenuView is auto wired to the MainMenuViewModel, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="xxx_App.Views.MainMenuView">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            // SOME BUTTONS
        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Here is my MainMenuViewModel constructor:

```
public MainMenuViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
    // A breakpoint here does break the software, but navigationService is null
}
```

**PROBLEM**: The problem is that navigationService is null in the MainMenuViewModel's constructor. The constructor DOES get called, so I don't think this is a problem with auto wiring. The constructor gets called by the PRISM framework's auto wiring function.

Does anybody have an idea as to why the navigationService is null?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

SOLUTION: I partly used Roubachof's solution.

I created a MainMenuPageViewModel. I got rid of the MainMenuViewModel, since this is not necessary anymore. I moved the ICommands (mentioned in comments) to the new MainMenuPageViewModel.

Clearly I got confused between pages and views when reading about PRISM. I thought a view had a viewmodel, but actually a page has a viewmodel. This happened because MVVM and Xamarin.Forms use different terminology. I'll go and make some changes to my application's structure now that I know this.

Comment: Can you add the code where you are creating your "MainMenuViewModel" ? I guess it is by view model locator from your MainMenuPageViewModel, but let us see that.

Comment: The MainMenuViewModel gets created by the PRISM framework. This is done with the auto wiring option. So that is external code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Prism uses class activation for creating sub view models and not view model locator, it only works for the Page view model.

But you are using `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"` in your inner view.
So you should use it on your ContentPage, and then have a matching `MainMenuPageViewModel`, with the injected navigation service.

In this parent view model you can create your sub view models and pass your dependencies.

Comment: The `ViewModelLocator` was never meant to be used for anything but top-level views anyway. If you're within a view and want a view model for a component of that view, create it from the "parent" view model. No need to go view first everywhere, view model first is very valid, too.

Comment: Thanks I'm trying this now. For some reason the MainMenuPageViewModel is not being created. (does this use the right naming convention?) I'll try to work this out and if I can't get it to work I will edit my post.

Comment: It works. The problem was that the MainMenuPage was in a namespace called 'Pages' and PRISM needs it to be in a namespace called 'Views'. So it works... but now the commands inside the MainMenuView don't call the ICommands in the MainMenuViewModel anymore. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If you want sub view models, you need to bind them explicitly to your sub views. For your MainMenuView, it will be like this: `<views:MainMenuView BindingContext="{Binding MainMenuViewModel}" />`, otherwise your content view will just inherit from the parent view model, here `MainMenuPageViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will not be using sub ViewModels